# How to get the textures attached to a framebuffer?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

At the moment I store framebuffers by their id and their number of render targets. But to draw into framebuffer I need to set the correct draw buffers using `glDrawBuffers`. For now I do it this way.

```
vector<GLenum> buffers;
for(int i = 0; i < targets; ++i)
{
    buffers.push_back(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i);
}
glDrawBuffers(targets, &buffers[0]);
```

For simplicity, I do not want to store the number of render targets myself anymore. I guess OpenGL do so anyway. Is there a way to fetch the color attachments bound to a framebuffer, e.g. the using `glFramebufferTexture2D` call?

Comment: I have the same issue, since Qt doesn't wanna give up the current texture ID of a QOpenGLWidget :( I didn't create these textures...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The draw buffers locations are part of the FBO's *state*. If you aren't changing them, you only have to set them *once*, at initialization time, where the number of targets should be well known.

However, if you insist on querying the attachments, you can [use `glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameter`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameter) with `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE​`. If the value you get back is `GL_NONE`, then there is no attachment for that binding point.

Comment: Thanks, I will set them at initialization time. And nice to know that you can even query them.

Comment: @sharethis: You can query *everything* in OpenGL.

Comment: I think the questioner wanted the texture IDs/names, so u need GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_NAME instead